# Using PHP classes to create objects controllable by Javascript/Jquery/CSS

Tags: javascript, php, oop

This might be really simple, however I'm breaking new grounds in my understanding and usage of PHP, so please bear with me.

Say I have the following PHP class:

```
<?php
class aBox {
    public $width;
    public $height;
    public $content;

    public function __construct($width, $height, $content) {
        $this->width = $width;
        $this->height = $height;
        $this->content = $content;
    }
}
```

When I create a new instance of the above class, how do I add it to the webpage? Ideally (I believe) I would want a id/class that I can control through JavaScript/jQuery/CSS afterwards.

Additionally, are PHP objects an optimal way of creating a template of this kind? Am I tunnel-visioned in the wrong direction, when there is a more optimal way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to write a `print()` function which returns the appropriate HTML Code and then you have to print/echo the return of that print-function. EG `public function print(){ return '<div Style="width:'.$this->width.'; height:'.$this->height.';">'.$this->content.'</div>';}`